# Converting curl command to Java or jQuery.ajax ()

Tags: java, ajax, curl, gson

I've never used `curl` before. I'm trying to run a command and parse the XML result in a web app.

```
curl -k https://ip.address.example --data-urlencode file.xml
```

So my options are limited to:

- Execute the command using a servlet with `Runtime.getRuntime.exec`
- Use `jQuery.ajax()`

I have tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://ip.address.example",
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    file: "file.xml",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error : function() {
        console.log("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

For the first method, I tried:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -k https://ip.address.example --data-urlencode file.xml");
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line , output = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output += line + "\n";
            }
            System.out.println(output);
            out.printf(gson.toJson(output));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

But i'm getting an error on `out.printf(gson.toJson(output));`

```
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ')'
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: --data-urlencode is used to POST data to a web server.  POSting a file cannot be accomplished so easily with jQuery.  For starters, jQuery.ajax doesn't even have a 'file' property in its settings.  For jQuery, you should look at some file upload plugins.  You could use the java method, if the file.xml is local to the servlet.  If not, you still have the hurdle of getting the file.xml uploaded to the servlet.

Comment: i tried the first method but something is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :
Replacing

```
out.printf(gson.toJson(output));
```

with   `out.printf(output);`